# I am looking for a word that is the same as "aspiration" but it's done

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, nouns, antonyms

For example if you wish to do or have something, you can use *aspiration*. What word is the best to use for things that you have and done already?

I was thinking about *accomplishment*, but it only applies to things we did. I want a word that combines the meaning of things we did and things we have right now.

It's hard to communicate what I need, so I give one more example:

> Alex's aspiration
>
> - playing piano
> - having a piano
> - other things that I use to do and have
>
> Alex's [word I am looking for]
>
> - I already learned playing piano
> - I bought a piano

Comment: Something like *expertise*?

Comment: A physical object is not an aspiration. You don't "aspire to a piano." You might "aspire to *own* a piano," but the piano itself would be your "desire," not your aspiration. Aspiration refers to an action, or to the embodiment of an active accomplishment. You have to aspire to *do* something, or to *be* something that you can accomplish (for example, "he aspires to be a piano player"). So your use of "aspiration" is a bit off target. And the word you seek, which would combine an achieved aspiration and a fulfilled desire into one word, is a concept I've never heard of.

Comment: Maybe you're going for *attainments*?

Comment: If you have't yet got there, you could say *"My aspirations include playing the piano and curing cancer"*. It might be [slightly] unlikely those particular aspirations would be realised - but if they were, you could reasonably say *"My **accomplishments** include playing the piano and curing cancer"*.

Comment: ***Wish*** -- A wish *fulfilled* is still a *wish* fulfilled. "Some of my wishes have been fulfilled, some still await their turn." Quite early in the question, you seem to have unwittingly used the word yourself!

Comment: *Achievement, attainment, accomplishment* mentioned by others are fine, but really you're just looking for "todo list" vs. "done" or "check". And typically you don't make a second list for that anyway, you just check off the items on the todo list.

Comment: JIC you are using this in anything that may be graded "I already learned playing the piano" should be "I have already learned to play the piano"

Answer (score 4):

I think the word ***Achievement*** is general enough to describe what you are trying to describe.  It is a slightly better fit than ***Accomplishment*** in the context you have.